# display searched data in listbox in vba

Tags: vba, excel

I am new to VBA coding..

help me in this situation..

I have a table like in sheet 1

[Data table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7QwUh.png)

& the user-form is like 
[User form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gYCc1.png)

I need to display the searched data in this list-box...my logic which i have tried...

1) a variable which holds the text-box value
2) 1st tried with advanced filter but its not working
3) then tried with find function it also shows error..

I have tried but it does not display in list-box...it is my first working with  list-box...thanks in advanced....

Comment: Have you figured out already the answer? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

can you please show your codes you have tried? I'm sorry if I can't just comment on your question coz I'm still lacking in reputation. Thanks!

Please Try this code below:

```
Private Sub cmdSearch_Click()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim numRow As Integer
Dim found As Boolean
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("display")
For numRow = 1 To (ws.Range("A" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)
        If nameTxtBox.Value = ws.Range("A" & numRow).Text Then
            nameList.AddItem (ws.Range("A" & numRow).Value)
            prodList.AddItem (ws.Range("B" & numRow).Value)
            saleList.AddItem (ws.Range("C" & numRow).Value)
            found = True
            Exit For
        End If
Next numRow
If found = False Then
    MsgBox "No Match Found!", vbCritical
    nameList.Clear
    prodList.Clear
    saleList.Clear

End If

End Sub
```

userForm screen shot

[image: userform]

Spread Sheet Screenshot:

[image: Spread Sheet]

hope this is what you want to do!
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The details might well vary between Access and Excel, and the version of those tools  ... I happened to use Access 2000 for this example.

In case you're not sure how to see what an icon is named: float the mouse cursor over it.

- I opened the form in design view
- I activated a toolbar that had the "Toolbox" icon
- I selected "List box"
- I clicked on the form and dragged a box shape. This made a caption box containing "List1:" and also a list box
- I changed the caption to whatever matches the table I plan to use, which is "tblDomainName" hence "Domain Name:"
- I opened up the properties for the list box and clicked in the "Row Source" area.
- I typed "SELECT DomainName FROM tblDomainName ORDER BY DomainName" based on the table planned to use, so if your table were named "Stuff" then you'd type what's inside the double-quotes, here: "SELECT [Name] FROM Stuff ORDER BY [Name]" ... notice the square brackets in case "Name" is a reserved word that might cause confusion otherwise.
- I changed to form "view" mode and clicked through the various values. They matched what's in my table, and they were sorted besides. Yay!

So, the above gets the list box basically working and gets you past your first hurdle ... as I understand it to be.

What's next? As to how you use that list box, and the selected value, to your benefit .... that depends on what the big picture is, so feel free to elaborate.

Does this help?

~Tanya